# How do I deserialize XML with child elements in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize/deserialize the following XML code structure:

```
<Person>
    <Name/>
    <Age/>
    <Address>
        <BuildingNumber/>
        <Street/>
        <Town/>
        <PostCode/>
    </Address>
</Person>
```

using the classes

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

I am implemeting `IXmlSerializable` on both classes (it's over-engineered for this specific example, I know, but it is required for a project I am working on which is rather more complicated!), for which serialisation works fine, but deserialisation does not.

The problem arises in the `Person.ReadXml()` method, which I have written as:

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
    reader.ReadStartElement();
    if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) {
        Name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("Name", string.Empty);
        Age = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt("Age", string.Empty);
        Address = (Address)reader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(Address), null, "Address", string.Empty);
        // Also failed: Address = (Address)reader.ReadElementContentAsObject("Address", string.Empty);
    }
    reader.ReadEndElement();
}
```

The final line where `Address` is being initialised is throwing an exception:

> ReadElementContentAs() methods cannot be called on an element that has child elements. (XmlException)

Basically, how would I handle elements with child elements using `IXmlSerializable`?

Comment: Why not use built in serialization libraries instead of trying to read the XML element by element ? Check lazy's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simply use `XmlSerializer` here:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
Person person = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Serialization is also very simple:

```
serializer.Serialize(stream, person);
```

If you will need to customize xml (not your current case), then just use xml serialization attributes.

Comment: I stated that it is highly over-engineered for this example; in the actual project I need to use serialisation (I cannot post that code here as it is closed source), I require the use of IXmlSerializable for the process. But yes, for the example I have included above, XmlSerializer would indeed be sufficient.

Comment: @BWHazel can you provide a little more info about why you required to use `IXmlSerializable`?

Comment: Mainly due to the structures already in place and it's use elsewhere in the project to keep consistency - that is the main reason I did not use the serialisation attributes. They may well work in this situation (unlike in another), so I may go with them instead!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    reader.ReadStartElement();
    Name = reader.ReadElementString("Name");
    Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadElementString("Age"));
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Address));
    Address = (Address) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.ReadEndElement();
}
```

- Note that it might be inefficient to new up a XmlSerializer for adress every time and caching it might be a good idea.
- This will work independent of if address implements IXmlSerializable or not
- As other have said, use IXmlSerializable only as last resort, if attributes will work it is a much better way.